# PHP mysqli_fetch_array missing some fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have crated a database that stores information about boats, when I tried to use this data in PHP it worked, then I added some new fields to the database but when I use them in PHP they return "Undefined index: fieldName".

From what I know it means that the index has not been set, so I checked the contents of the array to find that all of the fields are there except the new ones, however i am able to view them in phpmyadmin.

PHPMyAdmin:
See Image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65222600/phpmyadminshot.png

[image]

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include_once "php/connect.php";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vessels");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    print_r( $row );
}
?>
```

PHP Returns:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1 [idVessels] => 1 
    [1] => 1 [userId] => 1 
    [2] => cams boat [name] => cams boat 
    [3] => 1000000000 [price] => 1000000000 
    [4] => 0 [VAT] => 0 
    [5] => GBP [Currency] => GBP 
    [6] => UK [Location] => UK 
    [7] => ME [builder] => ME 
    [8] => ME [make] => ME 
    [9] => ME [model] => ME 
    [10] => 10/10/13 [yearConstructed] => 10/10/13 
    [11] => 1 [cabins] => 1 
    [12] => 1 [heads] => 1 
    [13] => 1 [#engines] => 1 
    [14] => ME [engineModel] => ME 
    [15] => 100 [enginePower] => 100 
    [16] => petrol [fuelType] => petrol 
    [17] => 122 [nominalLength] => 122 
    [18] => 122 [overallLength] => 122 
    [19] => 122 [waterlineLength] => 122 
    [20] => 122 [beam] => 122 
    [21] => 122 [maxDraft] => 122 
    [22] => leather [hullMaterial] => leather 
    [23] => MINT [hullType] => MINT 
    [24] => MINT [keeltype] => MINT 
    [25] => 122 [displacement] => 122 
    [26] => 122 [waterCapacity] => 122 
    [27] => 2014-01-10 02:18:39 [dateAdded] => 2014-01-10 02:18:39 
    [28] => For Sale [status] => For Sale )
```

and nowhere is description or primaryImageURL.

any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Odd. your php script is connecting to the correct database right, not a different one (prod vs. dev) ?

Comment: You need to post your table structure, your screen-shot could be the result of a join.

Comment: Yes check if its connecting to a different Db as mentioned by @miuw16

Comment: my guess is that `vessels` is a `View` and not a `Table` you will need to update your `vessels` `View` to include your newly added fields

Comment: You spelled `wessels` wrong! Glad I could help. Love, Chekov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, turns out i was using the project DB not my Dev DB

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference explicitly fields names:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT IdVessels, userId, name, description, primaryImageURL FROM vessels");
```

That way you'll be able to find the problem more quickly. If the db answer that the fields doesn't existe, probably you are pointing your connection to an old database.